# Ajax no data message

Tags: ajax

using the bellow JavaScript Ajax code, how can I know and inform the user when there is no data from the server

```
$.ajax({
    url: siteNear,
    data: 'myLang=IL&',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false, 
    error: function () {
        $('#sitesList').append('Ajax error');
        } ,
    onFailure: function () {
        $('#sitesList').append('Ajax failure');
        } ,
     statusCode: {
        404: function() {
        $('#sitesList').append('Error 404');
            }   
        } ,
    success: function (result) {
        $.each(result.deals,function(index,dat){
            $("#sitesList").append(
                '<li>'+
                '<p><strong>'+dat.Name+'</strong></p>'+
                '</li>'
            );
        });
        $('#sitesList').listview('refresh');
    }
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by no data? You mean if `result` is empty, some `result` property is empty or `result` is null?

Comment: Check if the result object is empty and display message accordingly.

Comment: yes I mean the result is empty or null, how can I check if the result is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: siteNear,
    data: 'myLang=IL&',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false, 
    error: function () {
        $('#sitesList').append('Ajax error');
        } ,
    onFailure: function () {
        $('#sitesList').append('Ajax failure');
        } ,
     statusCode: {
        404: function() {
        $('#sitesList').append('Error 404');
            }   
        } ,
    success: function (result) {
    if(typeof result!='object')
            alert("Server returns no data");
    else
    {
        $.each(result.deals,function(index,dat){
            $("#sitesList").append(
                '<li>'+
                '<p><strong>'+dat.Name+'</strong></p>'+
                '</li>'
            );
        });
        $('#sitesList').listview('refresh');
}
    }
})
```

For checking empty strings, you can do this:

```
if((result=='') || (result==null))
alert("Result empty"):
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will give you some idea,

1. In Success callback, check for empty result and display message accordingly.
2. If the result is not empty, display the actual data.

   ```
   success: function (result) {
       if (result == null || result.deals == null ||  result.deals.length ==0 )
       {
          //display message here
          $('#sitesList').empty().append('No data found');
           return;
       }

       $.each(result.deals,function(index,dat){
           $("#sitesList").append(
               '<li>'+
               '<p><strong>'+dat.Name+'</strong></p>'+
               '</li>'
           );
       });
       $('#sitesList').listview('refresh');
   }
   ```